# calling a function with multiple parameters stored in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I searched around and didn't really find a question regarding this.

So I have a function which can take multiple parameters ,(the number of parameters doesn't matter) something like this:

```
function print(){
    for(var i = 0; i<arguments.length; i++ ){
        console.log(arguments[i]);
    }
}
```

and I have all the parameters in an array, like:

```
var params = [param1,param2,...];
```

I need to call the function with those parameters stored in the params array. Well, I could do this if I knew the number of params:

```
print(params[0],params[1],...);
```

but I don't know the number of params and need a way to call the function with all of them.

Is there anyway I can do this? I tried using print.call(params), but the call method doesn't work that way.

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value from the URL parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter)

Comment: @GandalftheWhite: Something tells me you grabbed the wrong URL there... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ES5 and earlier, you're looking for [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), which all true JavaScript functions have:

```
console.log.apply(console, params);
```

...where `params` is your array.

`Function#apply` calls the function you call it on with a given `this` value (the first argument) and as many arguments as there are in the array you give it.

Note that it's not guaranteed that all host-provided functions (like `console.log`) will be true JavaScript functions. In modern browsers, however, `console.log` does have `apply`. YMMV on, say, IE9 and earlier.

In ES2015 (ES6) and later, you'd use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
// ES2015 and later only
console.log(...params);
```

...again where `params` is your array.